# Importing scala.reflect.runtime

Tags: scala

Why below code works in interpreter by default but in case of sbt project requires explicit importing of the dependencies?

```
Welcome to Scala 2.12.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_144).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import scala.reflect.runtime._
import scala.reflect.runtime._
```

vs

`sbt run` throws

```
object runtime is not a member of package reflect
```

without

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % "2.12.3"
```

in build.sbt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar situation occurs, for example, for

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._
```

It can be imported in REPL without any auxiliary actions but requires adding dependencies in sbt project.

The reasons is that when REPL starts it adds all the jars from lib directory into classpath (scala.bat in Windows)

```
set _TOOL_CLASSPATH=
if "%_TOOL_CLASSPATH%"=="" (
  for %%f in ("!_SCALA_HOME!\lib\*.jar") do call :add_cpath "%%f"
  for /d %%f in ("!_SCALA_HOME!\lib\*") do call :add_cpath "%%f"
)
```

And following jars present in !_SCALA_HOME!\lib\

```
..
jline-2.14.4.jar
scala-compiler.jar
scala-library.jar
scala-parser-combinators_2.12-1.0.6.jar
scala-reflect.jar
scala-swing_2.12-2.0.0.jar
scala-xml_2.12-1.0.6.jar
scalap-2.12.3.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the REPL depends on `scala-compiler` which depends on `scala-reflect`, so not putting them into the classpath of the code wouldn't save anything.

Comment: Agree this is confusing. It would be nice if REPL had an "export" function to export an sbt project.

Comment: @Alexey, "REPL depends on scala-compiler which depends on scala-reflect" - can you please point me to some documentation which describes that? Also, as per documentation "The scala and java.lang packages as well as object Predef are imported by default." and "reflect.runtime" is part of scala.* - isn't it?

Comment: @DrYWit 1. Documentation for scala-compiler depending on scala-reflect? You can see it in dependencies at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.12.6. Or for REPL needing to compile code? That seems kind of obvious, but https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/86e75db7f36bcafdd75302f2c2cca0c68413214d/build.sbt#L516.

Comment: @DrYWit 2. `scala` being imported by default only means that you can use `import reflect.runtime._` instead of `import scala.reflect.runtime._`. It doesn't imply anything being in this package: you can also use `import nonexistingPackage` and Scala will look for `scala.nonexistingPackage` and `java.lang.nonexistingPackage`!

Comment: @DrYWit OTOH, if you mean documentation for what is in REPL classpath by default, I don't think it exists, and you may want to report that at https://github.com/scala/bug.